# Finding prime factors of non-random key generator

Tags: algorithms, cryptography, randomness, primes

I have been working on a challenge i found on the internet. It is as follows:

> You've stumbled onto a significant vulnerability in a commonly used cryptographic library. It turns out that the random number generator it uses frequently produces the same primes when it is generating keys.
>
> Exploit this knowledge to factor the (hexadecimal) keys below, and enter your answer as the last six digits of the largest factor you find (in decimal).
>
> Key 1: 1c7bb1ae67670f7e6769b515c174414278e16c27e95b43a789099a1c7d55c717b2f0a0442a7d49503ee09552588ed9bb6eda4af738a02fb31576d78ff72b2499b347e49fef1028182f158182a0ba504902996ea161311fe62b86e6ccb02a9307d932f7fa94cde410619927677f94c571ea39c7f4105fae00415dd7d
>
> Key 2: 
>    2710e45014ed7d2550aac9887cc18b6858b978c2409e86f80bad4b59ebcbd90ed18790fc56f53ffabc0e4a021da2e906072404a8b3c5555f64f279a21ebb60655e4d61f4a18be9ad389d8ff05b994bb4c194d8803537ac6cd9f708e0dd12d1857554e41c9cbef98f61c5751b796e5b37d338f5d9b3ec3202b37a32f

These seem to be common RSA 1024-bit keys.

My approach to the problem was to implement [Pollard's rho algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) to find factors, then once a factor is found, try dividing the decimal form of the keys by that factor until it is not divisible anymore. Iterate.

Now, i used Pollard's rho and tried to divide until the key is not divided anymore because of the information the problem gave: the keys are not completely random.

But here comes the question: assuming the algorithm generates two primes and multiplies them to get a co-prime, which is the key, the low randomness doesn't help much, does it? I mean, even if both keys share a common factor, finding it the first time would take the regular-impractical-exponential time.

That seems to be the case, as my Python algorithm is running for about 5 hours now and has not found any factor to the second key, which i decided to start with.

As it is a challenge, i assume there is a practical way of finding the answer. 
So what im i doing wrong? Is just the algorithm choice wrong, as Pollard's rho is intended mainly for integer with small factors? Is my assumption that i can only use the lack of randomness after i find the first of the four factor, to then try to break the other key with the same factor, wrong?

I would like if someone could just point me in right direction, instead of just giving the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you have two numbers that:

1. both have two prime factors, and
2. you strongly suspect that they share a factor.

So one is $n_{1}=pq_{1}$ the other $n_{2}=pq_{2}$. What is their GCD?

> What happens when you apply Euclid' algorithm?

Comment: When a related problem was reported on the internet, a similar question came up: Assume you have a billion such keys, and some of them have common factors. How do you find them without calculating 1 billion x 1 billion GCDs? (Which I read is possible in reasonable time using some clever maths).